# Create Windows Form with Exception information on catch?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to find a way to create a nice windows form that will pop up when I encounter an unhandled exception. I currently have:

```
// Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException );

// Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler( CurrentDomain_UnhandledException );

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException( object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e )
{
    MessageBox.Show( e.ToString( ), "Unhandled Non-UI Thread Exception" );
}

static void Application_ThreadException( object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e )
{
    MessageBox.Show( e.ToString( ), "Unhandled UI Thread Exception" );
}
```

But what I'm looking for is to, in the threadexception methods, pop up a windows form with information about the error, and a continue/quit/restart whatever. This sounds very similar to something that, through gooogling, looks like its built in for certain cases, but is it possible to create some sort of modifiable / custom one that I can call?

Sorry, I unintentionally pasted the wrong part of code. I am currently using a message box, but want a somewhat more beefed out one with some functional buttons.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just create any old form, and display it using `ShowDialog` at that point.  You can put whatever you want on it.  You could then put various buttons on it for "continue", "restart", "quit", etc.  You can then inspect a property of the form after `ShowDialog` returns to determine what to do, based on the button clicked.

Comment: It sounds like with these actions he could probably just set the DialogResult property with a value from the Windows Forms enumeration (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) on button click, which is then returned by ShowDialog when the form closes. A little cleaner.

Comment: @ColeCameron That would work so long as as of his options directly map to one of those values, yes.

Answer (score 4):

How about popping a MessageBox ? Take a look here http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show

Answer (score 4):

All of your events should be wrapped in a code looking like this:

```
DialogResult result = DialogResult.Retry;
while (result == DialogResult.Retry) {
    try {
        DoProcess();
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        result = MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), 
                    "Error Information", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        if (result == DialogResult.Abort) throw;
    }
}
```

Where `DoProcess()` would be the risky code.

Comment: You need to catch Exception to the source in order to "Retry" the event. I don't see how you could use the `ex.StackTrace` to retrieve a string representation of the failing event and re-trigger that event...

Comment: @MLavine Does the solution contain enough explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom window that pop ups when you get an error. Then you can decide whether to close the application, continue or quit the a certain process.

The best approach i could think of is create a custom exception which you would throw when specific problems occur in your application. You should then allow this exception to bubble up and be handled in one of the following.

Application.ThreadException
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Check this link for more info.

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom message box. This should be inherited from From

```
class MyDialog : Form
    {
        //your properties like buttons and all goes here
    private Button okButton;
    private Button cancelButton;

        okButton = new Button();
        okButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        okButton.Location = new Point(20, 260);
        okButton.Size = new Size(80, 25);
        okButton.Text = "OK";
        okButton.Click += new EventHandler(okButton_ClickCompany);
        Controls.Add(okButton);

        //same implementation for all other controls you define
    }
```

you implementation goes like

```
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(); // you can constructor for using it everywhere
        if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             //you code goes here
        }
```

this is very good approach for doing it.
you can extend it according to you needs and use it in many ways by defining multiple constructor

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice sample in MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadexceptioneventargs.aspx